# SQL catch date from multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a problem:
I have a table in which I have the status of a switch (1 = ON, 0 = OFF) of a charger, and sometimes (we don't have a standard range of time) we detect the status.
Now, I need to calculate the average of a second field, between consecutives ON (sometimes there are 12/13 consecutives ON status), until I found a OFF (excluded from the average), for every range of ON status.
We have an ID field that identifies different chargers.
I hope I have been able to explain.

EDIT:
I'm sorry, I didn't explain well, I need to select start and end date (timestamp), that I will use to calculate the average in another table. Sorry for my mistake

I want a result like:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: @vincecassel Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: DDL statements to create your table; DML statements to create some sample data in your table; and your expected output for that sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` from Oracle 12:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER     BY "TIMESTAMP"
  MEASURES
    FIRST( "TIMESTAMP" )  AS timestamp_start,
    LAST( "TIMESTAMP" )   AS timestamp_end
  PATTERN ( status_on+ )
  DEFINE status_on AS status = 1
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  "TIMESTAMP" DATE,
  id          NUMBER,
  status      NUMBER(1,0)
              CHECK ( status IN ( 1, 0 ) )
);

INSERT INTO table_name ( id, "TIMESTAMP", status )
SELECT 1 AS device_id,
       DATE '2020-11-25' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND AS "TIMESTAMP",
       1 AS status
FROM   DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-11-26' + INTERVAL '18:15:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-11-27' + INTERVAL '18:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-11-28' + INTERVAL '18:45:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2020-11-29' + INTERVAL '19:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-11-25' + INTERVAL '18:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-11-26' + INTERVAL '18:15:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-11-27' + INTERVAL '18:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-11-28' + INTERVAL '18:45:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-11-29' + INTERVAL '19:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2020-11-30' + INTERVAL '19:15:00' HOUR TO SECOND, 0 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ID | TIMESTAMP_START     | TIMESTAMP_END      
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------
>  1 | 2020-11-25 18:00:00 | 2020-11-26 18:15:00
>  1 | 2020-11-28 18:45:00 | 2020-11-29 19:00:00
>  2 | 2020-11-26 18:15:00 | 2020-11-29 19:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eefd4cf5919d1203528832f13c572675)*

---

## Update

Or you can use analytic functions:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MIN( "TIMESTAMP" ) AS timestamp_start,
       MAX( "TIMESTAMP" ) AS timestamp_end
FROM   (
  SELECT "TIMESTAMP",
         id,
         status,
         SUM(1-status) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "TIMESTAMP" )
           AS grp
  FROM   table_name
) t
WHERE  status = 1
GROUP BY id, grp;
```

[Oracle db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0214f4630da269ec38fd32a77a03603a)

[PostgreSQL db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cf95adb905bdccdaf6ac165538897d5a)

Comment: Perfect answer,it works, thank you. 
Do you know, by chance, how to replicate it in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @vincecassel Updated. PostgreSQL does not support `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` but you can do it with analytic functions.

Comment: it looks like work very well! Thank you so much.
Can I ask you why you use SUM(1-status) over?

Comment: @vincecassel It is doing a cumulative sum as the timestamp increases to generate a value that you can group on. You want to increase the value between groups, when `status` is off (`0`), and keep it the same group with the status is on (`1`); the simplest way of doing it is to flip the status value using `1-status` but you could equally use `CASE` or `DECODE` instead.

Comment: Do you mean `MIN("TIMESTAMP") - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE`?

Comment: yes, but for the following grp (I think I solved with a left join from the one u gave me and another one with status=0 on 1.grp=0.grp-1)

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, this sounds like a gap-and-islands problem, where the islands are determined by counts of `'OFF'`.

However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There are no "adjacent rows" unless a column has that information.  Let me assume you have such a column.

That would then be:

```
select device_id, min(timecol), max(timecol), count(*) as num_ons,
       avg(other_col)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'OFF' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by device_id order by <timecol>) as island
      from t
     ) t
where status = 'ON'
group by device_id, island;
```